# What does it mean by `...` parameters in a function?

Tags: vimscript, functions

I often see vim function with function definition written like this:

```
function! MyFunction(...)
" function body...
endfunction
```

What does the `...` do within the function?

Comment: [`:h ...`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#...)

Answer (score 5):

#### Explanation

It means variadic arguments (see [`:h ...`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#...)). To get all the extra arguments as a list, you use `a:000`. To get the i-th extra arguments use `a:i` where `i` is the integer (equivalent to `a:000[i-1]`). `a:0` represents the number of extra arguments `a:0 == len(a:000)`

#### Example

To check whether an extra argument is supplied you do

```
if a:0
    let arg1 = a:1  " let a:000[0]
else
    let arg1 = arg1_default
endif
```

More conveniently, the previous snippet is equivalent to (Note that the second parameter is `0` to denote the first element in the list `a:000`)

```
let arg1 = get(a:000, 0, arg1_default)
```

#### Forward the variadic parameters

Some times you may need to forward the variadic parameters to another function using the same order. For example, if `MyFunc` should call `s:MyFuncImpl` with all the variadic parameters passed, you can do the following in `MyFunc`

```
call call('s:MyFuncImpl', a:000)
```

Here the first call is the command `call`, see `:h :call`, the second call is a function, see `:h call()`.

#### Handle a large amount of extra arguments

Personally, if the potential number of extra arguments is large or when I anticipate to have more and more extra arguments to the function when the plugin evolves, I will use a single `dict` to represent the extra arguments. So I use the following pattern

```
function! MyFunc(x, y, ...)
    let opts   = get(a:000, 0, {})
    let method = get(opts, 'method', 'default')
    let buf    = get(opts, 'buf', buf('%'))
    " other statements
endfunction
```

Here, the function `get` can deal with both `list` and `dict`. Now, you call it using `call MyFunc(x, y, {'method': 'best'})` if `method` is different from the default and `buf` should use the default. This makes the function more adaptable and more readable.

Comment: @JohnFredFadrigalan If you are satisfied with this answer, please remember to mark it as "accepted" with the green button under the vote button: that will allow future users to know your question has an answer which could help them.